# Storing values in an array using a while loop

Tags: function, loops

For the data set here, I am trying to extract a velocity and an acceleration array using the forward difference equation. I'm trying to use a while loop to store the values into the array while condensing the code, however it only gives me the first value of the velocity matrix. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with my code? Thank you

```
#          Time, t, second    0  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16
#          Position, x, meter 0 0.7 1.8 3.4 5.1 6.3 7.3 8.0 8.4

# 2a) Use forward difference

t=np.arange(0,16,2)
x=[0,0.7,1.8,3.4,5.1,6.3,7.3,8.0,8.4]

# Velocity
def df(t,x,i):
    return (x[i+1]-x[i])/(t[i+1]-t[i])

# Acceleration
def d2f(t,x,i):
    return (x[i+2]-2*x[i+1]+x[i])/((t[i+1]-t[i])^2)

# Finding velocity array
i=0
velo=[]

while i<len(t)-1:
    velo=df(t,x,i)
    i=i+1
print('Velocity Array')
print(velo)
```

Comment: You are assigning a scalar value to velo. Velo is NOT an array any longer after this. The code will output the last value. You want to append the value to the array instead, using velo.append(df(t,x,i)).

Comment: I tried doing same for the acceleration array, which works, however, I am getting values of infinity. What do you think could be causing that? Here is the acceleration code below:

Comment: # Finding acceleration array
i=0
accel=[]

while i<len(t)-2:
    accel.append(d2f(t,x,i))
    i=i+1

print('Acceleration Array')
print(accel)

Comment: What language is this? Please add the tag of the language to the question.